# Installing ByeBug in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, debugging

I tried to install ByeBug since debugger is no longer working in ruby 2.2.x. I already installed devkit gem. But now all it does when I try to install ByeBug gem
it says following. Also any other previous version gives the same error.

"Following gems were not installed:
byebug (4.0.5): Cancelled"

Comment: Actually `debugger` is not compatible with the Ruby 2.x line :). Can you check if you installed a C compiler? `byebug` is a native extension, make sure you have the necessary tools to build it.

Comment: A C compiler is a program that translate C programs to machine readable code. Just make sure you selected `GNU GCC` and `Make` in the DevKit installation wizard.